# How do I use window.fetch() with httpOnly cookies or basic auth

Tags: javascript, dom, cookies, basic-authentication, fetch-api

I'm playing around with [window.fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch) in Firefox and Chrome. For some reasons, fetch() doesn't send any cookies. Now that wouldn't be a problem, as I can send them using

```
fetch('/something', { headers: { Cookie: document.cookie } })
```

But this won't work for httpOnly cookies.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Okay, I found out after reading on the Mozilla Developer Network a bit more and trying out the credentials option.

Looks like the credentials option is what I should have looked for.

```
fetch('/something', { credentials: 'same-origin' }) // or 'include'
```

Will send the cookies.

Comment: Here is the MDN article. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials

`'omit'` is the default, and doesn't send any cookies. `'same-origin'` will send cookies if the endpoint lives on the same uri. `'include'` will send cookies to all uris.

Comment: Just ran into this, thank a lot! Helped me out a ton.

Comment: In recent browsers 'same-origin' become the default value, but it can be explicitely written for back compatibility. In Firefox, this default value is from version 61 (released 26 June 2018).

Comment: Does this mean `same-origin` or `include` imply httpOnly?

Comment: @YoshuaWuyts seems like 'same-origin' is the default now.

Comment: This will still not work for httpOnly cookies and that is good.

Comment: @NagabhushanBaddi It works for httpOnly cookies too.

Answer (score 4):

There are three points here:

1. If you're making a cross-origin request, set the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`. So that the server accepts your cookies.
2. Set the credentials options either to `include` for cross-origin requests or `same-origin` for same-origin requests
3. Set the `credentials` option of fetch on both requests that you retrieve and send the cookie

Comment: We were missing step 3! Thanks.