# Fetch API with Cookie

Tags: cookies, fetch-api

I am trying out the new Fetch API but is having trouble with Cookies. Specifically, after a successful login, there is a Cookie header in future requests, but Fetch seems to ignore that headers, and all my requests made with Fetch is unauthorized.

Is it because Fetch is still not ready or Fetch does not work with Cookies?

I build my app with Webpack. I also use Fetch in React Native, which does not have the same issue.

Answer (score 391, accepted):

Fetch does not use cookie by default. To enable cookie, [do this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters):

```js
fetch(url, {
  credentials: "same-origin"
}).then(...).catch(...);
```

Comment: same-origin doesn't work anymore, include does (see @Jerry's answer): https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch

Comment: @jpic: 'include' only works for cross-origin requests, but not for same-origin requests.  Official docs: https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies

Comment: What is the reason then to have httponly cookies if they are readable in js with fetch ?

Comment: I believe `same-origin` (which *does* still work) means that more headers will be respected (cookies, etc) but your code will have limited access to the response.

Comment: Wasted a lot of time trying to figure out the problem in the server side. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MartinBajcar parameter "credentials" in fetch is not reading any cookie, it only acts as a door, if opened(credentials: 'include'), cookies will be allow to pass, if not opened then they aren't.

Comment: @JohnBalvinAriasThx. As I later understood, having cookie httponly means that it's not readable by `document.cookie`, but still available to ajax or fetch requests.

Comment: i am unable to get "set-cookie" parameter in response headers in fetch api in android. in ios i am getting it for first time. how to get "set-cookie" every time i login in both android and ios. i used to achieve this in native ios by setting setHTTPShouldHandleCookies to NO. thanks in advance

Comment: @DhanunjayKumar If you have a new question, please use the Ask Question button. Comments are not a good avenue for getting questions answered.

Comment: @HereticMonkey : i have added as question also 
link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904745/not-getting-set-cookie-in-headers-if-i-call-login-frequently-in-reactnative

Comment: Hello guys, I was reading this question, and I have a similar one, which my cookies are set to HttpOnly and from javascript when I fetch an API it redirects to login url because it cannot reach the cookies, where credentials:same-origin didnt work for me, can you please check my question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59311203/cannot-read-property-undefined

Comment: what if we have different origins.

Comment: same origin is the default value now.  assuming this is cors, which was my issue when I came here, @zurfyx answer should probably be the accepted one.

Answer (score 318):

In addition to @Khanetor's answer, for those who are working with cross-origin requests: `credentials: 'include'`

Sample JSON fetch request:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  credentials: 'include'
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
    console.log('Gotcha');
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials

Comment: how do you set the cookie though?

Comment: The cookie is set from server-side. In my case I was using httponly cookies.

Comment: @Khanetor can I set cookies using the document.cookie by javascript, and then send the request?

Comment: @ospider You can send it in the header.

Comment: Interesting fact: I wanted to cover both cases of fetch with same-origin and cross-origin by using this, and I could not, but it did work for cross-origin requests. =)

Comment: @ospider I found that just setting the value in `document.cookie` was enough for it to be included in the requests.

Comment: i am unable to get "set-cookie" parameter in response headers in fetch api in android. in ios i am getting it for first time. how to get "set-cookie" every time i login in both android and ios. i used to achieve this in native ios by setting setHTTPShouldHandleCookies to NO. thanks in advance

Comment: If you're using a rails API and keep getting CORS issues with `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` make sure in your Rack::Cors config you set `credentials: true` on the resource.

Comment: @pomo dough* - refrigerate it for 24hrs, it should be fully set by then

Comment: See this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74948785/14226292)

Comment: This made an end to my countless hour journey on why setting my cookie doesn't work. Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 124):

Have just solved. Just two f. days of brutforce

For me the secret was in following:

1. I called POST /api/auth and see that cookies were successfully received.
2. Then calling GET /api/users/ with `credentials: 'include'` and got 401 unauth, because of no cookies were sent with the request.

The KEY is to set `credentials: 'include'` for the first `/api/auth` call too.

Comment: I have exactly your problem. The session cookie is never sent on the GET data request. so 401. I have tried Axios and Fetch. same result. 2 possibilities: the login POST doesnt store the received cookie or the following GET data doesnt send the stored cookie

Comment: @Rhubarb65, to win this u should specify `credentials: 'include'` for first `POST /api/auth`

Comment: Yes, I had that but it want enough. I use a devserver proxy (client Http)

Comment: Yes, I had credentials but it was not enough. I was using a devserver proxy to get past CORS: (client http) - proxy - (server https). I believe this meant that the sessionid cookie from the server was not set in the browser because secure cookies require https. So I added the flag https: true in the devserver proxy and that fixed it

Comment: Well cheers. Your answer meant it only took me 1 day of bruteforce. :)

Comment: As I remember, used browser dev tools and backend logs (request data) to understand that no cookies were sent. After I randomly (i think so, may be from google search) added needed param to first auth call. PS hehe - found that in profile my location is moon (:

Comment: I owe you a big fat pint of beer. I've been banging my head against the desk for the past 3 hours trying to solve this issue. Thank you x1000.

Comment: Also, don't be me. Make sure the fetch URL is 127.0.0.1 not localhost, or the Cookie won't be set.

Comment: That's amazing! I would never have thought to try that. What's the rationale to also need to try and send a cookie on the first request?

Comment: You are a legend. 2 days of bruteforce here as well until I read your answer.

Answer (score 35):

If you are reading this in 2019, `credentials: "same-origin"` is the default value.

```
fetch(url).then
```

Comment: But note that not everyone is using a sufficiently updated browser. I came across this question because my own version of Firefox (60.x, the most recent in Debian Stretch) doesn't set that by default.

Answer (score 23):

Programmatically overwriting `Cookie` header in browser side **won't work**.

In `fetch` documentation, [Note that some names are forbidden.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#parameters) is mentioned. And `Cookie` happens to be one of the forbidden header names, which cannot be modified programmatically. Take the following code for example:

- Executed in the Chrome DevTools console of page https://httpbin.org/, `Cookie: 'xxx=yyy'` will be ignored, and the browser will always send the value of `document.cookie` as the cookie if there is one.
- If executed on a different origin, no cookie is sent.

```js
fetch('https://httpbin.org/cookies', {
  headers: {
    Cookie: 'xxx=yyy'
  }
}).then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)));
```

P.S. You can create a sample cookie `foo=bar` by opening https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/foo/bar in the chrome browser.

See [Forbidden header name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name) for details.

Comment: It works for me: `headers: { Cookie: cookies().toString() },`

Answer (score 4):

Just adding to the correct answers here for `.net` `webapi2` users.

If you are using `cors` because your client site is served from a different address as your `webapi` then you need to also include `SupportsCredentials=true` on the server side configuration.

```
        // Access-Control-Allow-Origin
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(Settings.CORSSites,"*", "*");
        cors.SupportsCredentials = true;
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Comment: 'cors.SupportsCredentials = true;' saved my day, thanks.

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question. This is about browser APIs and React Native, not some other platform.

Comment: @OlegMihailik this was just to point out that not setting up CORS correctly will cause a similar error.  My answer is not releated to React Native; though, I suspect, it could manifest there as well.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
const cookies = new Cookies();

function headers(set_cookie=false) {
  let headers = {
    'Accept':       'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
};
if (set_cookie) {
    headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + cookies.get('remember_user_token');
}
return headers;
}
```

Then build your call:

```
export function fetchTests(user_id) {
  return function (dispatch) {
   let data = {
    method:      'POST',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    mode:        'same-origin',
    body:        JSON.stringify({
                     user_id: user_id
                }),
    headers:     headers(true)
   };
   return fetch('/api/v1/tests/listing/', data)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(receiveTests(json)));
    };
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was trying to figure out!! `'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')` saved the day!

Answer (score 2):

### If it still doesn't work for you after fixing the credentials.

I also was using the :

```
  credentials: "same-origin"
```

and it used to work, then it didn't anymore suddenly, after digging much I realized that I had change my website url to `http://192.168.1.100` to test it in LAN, and that was the url which was being used to send the request, even though I was on `http://localhost:3000`.

**So in conclusion, be sure that the domain of the page matches the domain of the fetch url.**

Comment: Any ideas if it's port specific? Curious how this works when the host is the same but the port is different? (ie. UI server + backend server)

Comment: Hello @Ryan Yes actually it may seem that ports aren't related to cors but they are : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19966782/10268067

Comment: note, that also localhost is not the same as 127.0.0.1 - your backend needs to be on the exact same ip address than your frontend

Comment: or.. just use include instead of same-origin.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was my cookie was set on a specific URL path (e.g., `/auth`), but I was `fetch`ing to a different path. I needed to set my cookie's `path` to `/`.

Answer (score 1):

I wasted three hours looking for a solution so I decided to share my findings.

```
login(email: string, password: string): Promise<User | null> {

  return fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: email,
      password: password,
    }),
  })
      .then(response => {
        this.handleError(response);
        return response.ok ? response.json() : null;
      })
}
```

1. "credentials: 'include'" parameter must be set in the request that receives `Set-Cookies` header, not just subsequent request that we expect to carry the cookie;
2. **Most most importantly `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` returned by the server MUST list all possible headers that client MAY send.** Contrary to your expectation wildcard asterisk value won't work. If client sends at least one unknown header it will also break cors.

Answer (score 0):

If the `fetch` is not sending credentials even though the request is not intended to be a cross-origin call, it could be because the request is being processed as cross-origin due to differences in protocols between the origin of the request and location of the response.

I observed that my server was returning `Location` header with an `http` URL, while the connection was established over `https`. As a result, the browser treated the request as cross-origin and applied cross-origin rules. It's worth noting that Firefox (version 114.0.2) and Safari (version 16.1) didn't display any warnings in this scenario, but Chrome (version 114.0.5735.198) showed a `(blocked:mixed-content)` error, which helped in identifying the issue.

If anyone is interested, in this particular case, SSL termination was being performed in the reverse-proxy, but the `gunicorn` server was not correctly handling it due to misconfiguration, specifically related to the `secure-scheme-headers` and `forwarded_allow_ips` settings. After resolving these settings on the server side, `fetch` started working fine in all browsers.