# Fetch API making requests to rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, fetch-api

Using the fetch API to make calls to the Rails server is causing a few problems that did not occur when using ajax.

1. CSRF, with jquery the rails gem automatically places the CSRF token in requests, is there a way to accomplish a similar effect with fetch?
2. Session cookie is not persisting page reloads. I am using a session token to store a current users session and logging in then refreshing wipes the session when it should be preserved.

Have been unable to find any resources on this subject, and I have used the exact same code successfully when making calls via ajax so I know the problem is related to my switch to fetch

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm working on figuring this one out right now. I'll update this answer when I figure it out. But the basic idea is that you need to pass the 'X-CSRF-Token' header. You can get the csrf token using this code, if you're using jQuery:

   ```
   $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
   ```
2. By default, `fetch` doesn't include cookies. You have to pass this option: `credentials: 'same-origin'`. See this question: [Fetch API with Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558264/fetch-api-with-cookie)