# Proper Django CSRF validation using fetch post request

Tags: javascript, django, django-csrf, fetch-api

I'm trying to use JavaScript's [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) library to make a form submission to my Django application. However no matter what I do it still complains about CSRF validation.

The docs on Ajax mentions specifying [a header](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request) which I have tried.

I've also tried grabbing [the token from the templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it) and adding it to the form data.

Neither approach seems to work.

Here is the basic code that includes both the form value and the header:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('file', file);;
data.append('fileName', file.name);
// add form input from hidden input elsewhere on the page
data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', $('#csrf-helper input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').attr('value'));
let headers = new Headers();
// add header from cookie
const csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
headers.append('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);
fetch("/upload/", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
    headers: headers,
})
```

I'm able to get this working with JQuery, but wanted to try using `fetch`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Figured this out. The issue is that `fetch` [doesn't include cookies by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558264/fetch-api-with-cookie).

Simple solution is to add `credentials: "same-origin"` to the request and it works (with the form field but without the headers). Here's the working code:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('file', file);;
data.append('fileName', file.name);
// add form input from hidden input elsewhere on the page
data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', $('#csrf-helper input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').attr('value'));
fetch("/upload/", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
    credentials: 'same-origin',
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the simplest solution I've seen so far and it works like a charm.

Comment: @Dr.DOOM I would think so, you'd just need to use the flask-specific way of accessing the token and passing it to the view.

Answer (score 24):

Your question is very close to success. Here is a **json** way if you do not want the form method. Btw, @Cory's form method is very neat.

1. Neat way with 3rd library

```js
let data = {
    'file': file,
    'fileName': file.name,
};
// You have to download 3rd Cookies library
// https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax
let csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
let response = fetch("/upload/", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken },
})
```

2.
Another cumbersome way, but without any 3rd library

```js
let data = {
    'file': file,
    'fileName': file.name,
};
let csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
let response = fetch("/upload/", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken },
})

// The following function are copying from 
// https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

Comment: somehow the accepted answer by Cory did not work for me. neither did the super simple one by Abhinas of just typing {{csrf_token}} but here the second one worked like a charm. I also don't see it as particularly cumbersome, copy & pasting one javascript function is a small price to pay and I definitely prefer it to adding a library.

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple solution to this without any third party libraries.
In your templates scripts. Do this.

```
fetch("your_post_url",
        {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: { "X-CSRFToken": '{{csrf_token}}' },
        }
    ).then(res => {
        //process your response
    }
```

Comment: i tried this, but i still get the error, the output in the Python terminal is `Forbidden (CSRF token from the 'X-Csrftoken' HTTP header has incorrect length.): /tweet`