# How can I make a POST-request using Javscript in Django (CSRF-Token)?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

This question has been asked before, but those solutions didn't work for me that well:

[Fetch, set-cookies and csrf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893537/fetch-set-cookies-and-csrf)

[Proper Django CSRF validation using fetch post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606056/proper-django-csrf-validation-using-fetch-post-request)

Right now the content of my post request is correct and being, but the 403 error still shows up.

```
        const url = "/post/create"
        let csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken'); //using library


        const headers = new Headers({
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrftoken
            });
            return fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers,
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                mode: 'same-origin',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    content: content
                })
            });
```

Do you have any ideas?

EDIT: This is the solution I found

```
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: "same-origin",
            headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
                "Accept": "network/json",
                "Content-Type": "network/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                content: content
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `X-CSRFToken` not `X-CSRF-TOKEN`. See more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request).

Comment: It's really weird but when I use X-CSRFToken the POST request isn't even submited. It only works with the latter on for me:(

Comment: If you're using jquery you may send it as a part of post data, like `var postData = $('your-form').serializeArray(); postData['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = Cookies.get('csrftoken');` and send `$.post(url, postData,...);`