# Django CSRF Validation – Using JavaScript Fetch POST-request to send FormData Object

Tags: javascript, django, fetch-api, django-csrf

**Update #1 – 7/26/23:** Per the comment by [@thebjorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75103/thebjorn), I attempted to set the `Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and set the token name to `csrfmiddlewaretoken` but the error still persists.

For reference, here are the implementations I tested, incase I am missing anything:

1. Adding the CSRF Token and Content-Type directly to the headers in the request:

```
headers: new Headers({
  'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken
})
```

2. Appending the token to the form data: `coverPhotoForm.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken')`
3. Including both `csrfmiddlewaretoken` and `X-CSRFToken` (seemed redundant but tested for continuity).

---

**Original Post:**
I am trying to use Django's CSRF protection when sending a dynamically created `FormData` object, containing an image file, to a Django endpoint using JavaScript `fetch` POST request. My issue is that I have been unable to successfully attach the `csrf_token` to the request, which is causing a `CSRF token missing` error.

Per [Django's CSRF Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/csrf/#acquiring-csrf-token-from-html), I have included `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True` in `settings.py`, and then I am setting the hidden `{% csrf_token %}` in my HTML file, and trying to access it in my JavaScript file:

```
// Create form to send image
let coverPhotoForm = new FormData();
        
// Read CSRF token and image file from DOM
const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
const coverPhotoUpload = document.querySelector('#cover-photo-upload');

// Add CSRF token and image to form object
coverPhotoForm.append('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken)
coverPhotoForm.append('cover_photo', coverPhotoUpload.files[0]);

// Add image via POST request to endpoint
  fetch(`/profile/${profileUserId}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: coverPhotoForm,
    mode: 'same-origin'
  })
  .then( response => response.json())
  .then( response => {
    console.log(response)
  })
})
```

**Notes:**

1. *`csrftoken` seems to be read from the DOM successfully when checked via `console.log`.*
2. *When the page is refreshed, images are uploaded successfully, but the `CSRF token missing` error still occurs each time a request is sent.*

I have also tried setting the headers directly within the `fetch` request above, and using the Django docs example below, but that didn't change anything.

```
const request = new Request(
    fetch(`/profile/${profileUserId},
    {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
        mode: 'same-origin'
    }
);
```

**Additional Attempts:**

1. My design above is adapted from the accepted answer from this SO post: [Proper Django Fetch Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606056/proper-django-csrf-validation-using-fetch-post-request).
2. Tried Adding `accept` and `content-type` keys to the `headers` dict in my request, suggested here: [POST request Using JS/Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66313525/how-can-i-make-a-post-request-using-javscript-in-django-csrf-token).
3. Added the `@ensure_csrf_cookie` decorator to my `view` as suggested in the 'Warning' in the Django Docs link included above for dynamically created forms.
4. Used `csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'` (instead of `querySelector` to read from DOM) per: [Using CSRF Token in JS](https://csrfmiddlewaretoken:%20%27%7B%7B%20csrf_token%20%7D%7D%27)

Comment: If you're sending as form data, then you'll need to set the header `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` and send the csrf-token in the form data with name `csrfmiddlewaretoken`. I'm unsure if you need to set the `X-CSRFToken` headers when using form-data, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: @thebjorn I could not fit my response in the comments, so I updated the post with the results of my testing, per your suggestion. Unfortunately, I have not gotten it to work, but if I am missing something, please let me know.