# Fetch request is not sending my cookies, what is the fault?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a problem with my `fetch` request. For some reasons, it isn't sending my cookies when I'm making request to my server. For example, I'm using such fetch request

```
fetch('/api/islogged', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache': 'no-cache'
      },
      credentials: 'include',
    })
```

and even if I'm already logged in, it still says that I'm not. But, if I go directly to `www.localhost.com/api/islogged` in my browser, it returns correct answer

Comment: From what you're saying it seems like you are running a local server so it shouldn't be the cause, but just in case, know that cookies won't work from a local HTML file opened directly in the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch API with Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558264/fetch-api-with-cookie)

Comment: @VipinKumar Possibly not since he is using  credentials: 'include', which is an answer in the duplicate

Answer (score -2):

Try using `credentials: 'same-origin'` instead of `include`. That should work.