# Fetch returns 302

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I switched my AJAX request code to...

```
return fetch("computerssuck?" + qs)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {

                ...
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

And now it returns 302 and no response.

When I request the same page using the browser or using XMLHttpRequest it works and returns 200 and some JSON.

Why does `Fetch` not work?

Here is the original code...

```
xhr.open('get', "computerssuck?" + qs, true);

xhr.onload = function () {

    ...

}.bind(this);

xhr.send();
```

Both sets of code work locally on my dev machine.

Chrome says, "Failed to load response data." in the inspector and some JSON parsing code crashes.

Comment: Are you sending the correct headers? Are you sure you're getting back JSON? etc. etc. And what do you mean by 'no response'? 302 is a redirect

Comment: What was your original XMLHttpRequest code?

Comment: Is the route correct?

Comment: @JaredSmith It works locally too.

Comment: @JaredSmith Chrome says "Failed to load response data" and some JSON parsing code crashes.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` doesn't send an authentication cookie by default.

Solution is here... [Fetch API with Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558264/fetch-api-with-cookie/34592377#34592377)