# Laravel 5.6 Auth::check() return false if called with fetch

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, authentication, fetch

I want to check if user is logged in through JavaScript `fetch()` function. But it always returns false, but if I called the URL directly in address bar, it returns true as it is supposed to. Here is the code:

**/routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('check-login', function () {
    if (Auth::check()) {
       return response()->json(['isLogin'=>'ok']);
    } else  {
       return response()->json(['isLogin'=>'no']);
    }
});
```

**javascript:**

```
fetch('/check-login', {
            headers:{
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
            });
```

What's wrong with my method?

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558264/fetch-api-with-cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's because you aren't specifying that credentials should be included, Fetch Api don't use cookie by default. So maybe like this it will work:

```
fetch('/check-login', {
        headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know your javascript code right or wrong but routes\web.php must be

```
Route::get('check-login', function () {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return response()->json(['isLogin'=>'ok']);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['isLogin'=>'no']);
    }
});
```

This code equivalent (more readability)

```
Route::get('check-login', function () {

   if (Auth::check()) {
       return response()->json(['isLogin'=>'ok']);
   }

   return response()->json(['isLogin'=>'no']);

});
```

Or you can use ternary operator

```
Route::get('check-login', function () {
   $isLogin = Auth::check() ? 'ok' : 'no';
   return response()->json(['isLogin'=> $isLogin]); 
});
```

Comment: yup sorry for the typo, the return statement is exist in my code, i just forgot to type in when creating this thread.