# Rails 5 Api Only with React Native New Session Id Each Time

Tags: session-cookies, react-native, ruby-on-rails-5.1

- React Native V 0.56 for Android
- Rails 5.1.3 API Only

My Rails app was able to persist session, but suddenly after upgrading React Native to 0.56 the Rails is creating a new session every time on each api request.

Unable to understand why the session is getting reset each time.

My application.rb looks like this

```
module AppService
    class Application < Rails::Application
        config.load_defaults 5.1
        config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
        config.middleware.use Rack::MethodOverride
        config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies

        config.api_only = true
        config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, key: '_namespace_key'
    end
end
```

Can someone please point out what can be the issue?
How can I debug this?

UPDATE
Digging a bit deeper I came across this
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/19770

Seems like this is a bug with RN 0.56. Can someone please suggest how this can be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a very similar problem and the issue was, as part of React Native V 0.56  upgrade, I also had to upgrade my nodejs version to 8. In node8 (may be even in prior versions) `fetch()` needs `credentials: 'include'` option to send cookies with requests. Not having the session cookies in your request could be the reason why your sever is creating a new session every time.

`fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  credentials: 'include'
})`

This [SO question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558264/fetch-api-with-cookie) may shed more light into the problem and solution.

Comment: For me this is working with android and not with iOS.

Comment: For other readers, this issue again occurs with latest version i.e. 0.57 RN in iOS. More info here..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54163056/cookies-set-in-a-redirect-response-are-not-persisted