# Cookies set in a redirect response are not persisted

Tags: session-cookies, react-native-ios

This appears to be a related issue only on iOS: since updating React Native from 0.55 to 0.57.
adding credentials: 'include' helps, but this flag does not help if you reopen the app. Cookie will be deleted after app relaunch.

Below link actually proposes a PR release around this, but even that is not resolving the error.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/a6860487947ae0957f5dfa4979e92bc7740fecb0

This is addition to the file `react-native/Libraries/Network/RCTHTTPRequestHandler.mm`

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
              task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
willPerformHTTPRedirection:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response
        newRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *))completionHandler
{
  // Add the cookies to the new request
  // This is necessary because we're not letting iOS handle cookies by itself
  NSMutableURLRequest *nextRequest = [request mutableCopy];

  NSArray<NSHTTPCookie *> *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:request.URL];
  nextRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookies];
  completionHandler(nextRequest);
}
```

Comment: Also, Is there anyway to debug this? I am really surprised with the support on Stack-overflow for React Native. None of the issues are really addressed/solved by anyone. Are people still using React Native?

Comment: hey there,did you ever end up solving this? im at that place now myself

Comment: I ended up using AsyncStorage to Manage Cookies on each request.

Comment: true, i was doing the same, but how did you manage to getting around the redirect? this was the main problem for me. if i could manually follow the redirect after setting the cookies on my own it would be fine. but since the redirect is handled by the fetch implementation code there's no way for me to access the cookies that come with it as the same repsonse that redirects also sets the new cookie. thank you for taking the time, this is madness. i proposed documentation changes on react-native-website to help others.

Comment: on `response` in `fetch` you can access `cookies` as: `response.headers.get("set-cookie");`

Comment: thats true. but if you receive a response that both has `set-cookie` and also redirects with say `302` then you cant access that set-cookie header as the redirect is handled by the client and there's no way of overriding it. i think we might be speaking of a different issue : /.

Comment: Yes, I didn't have to encounter this case.