# Can Javascript React send HttpOnly cookie to Server?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, httponly

### Can you, using fetch or by some other means send request with HttpOnly cookie to server in React ?

I know HttpOnly means you can't access it with JS.
I'm thinking maybe you can't read it but you can send it back? I don't know.

### I want this:

- Request to server is made from client (ReactJS SPA)
- Server responds and sets HttpOnly Cookie.
- Client gets response, cookie is automatically set by browser.

With new request to that same server I want to send back that cookie. is this possible using ReactJS ?
or maybe there are some ways to bypass that, like maybe opening new window, with simple HTML, not ReactDOM ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `React` has nothing to do with sending cookies back to the server with each request. If you're using `fetch`, make sure the `credentials` options is set appropriately if you want to include cookies with your requests - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch API with Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558264/fetch-api-with-cookie)

Comment: Maybe, I wannted to know if cookies with httpOnly set tu true, will be still sent

Comment: Give it a try and let us know. As per MDN docs, "a cookie with the HttpOnly attribute is inaccessible to the JavaScript Document.cookie API; it is sent only to the server."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Ok, I checked it out.**

Cookie with HttpOnly set with true, **will still be send using ReactJS, fetch or any other Request made with JS**, You just Can't read it using JS, but when using HttpPost, HttpGet, or other. Browser still attaches it to request, even if it's HttpOnly.

I guess the lesson here is that **browser handles setting cookies to requests**, and it doesn't care if request is made by HTML, or JavaScript.