# Cors cookies and ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, express, cookies

I am working with an `MVC` server with IIS express on port x.
I run my client code using `express` server on port y, and send my requests for data to the server on localhost:x

The issue here is that the SessionId cookie is not sent back to the server on every request due to CORS.
I read that the cookie will not be sent to a different domain in case the cookie is not set to `SameSite->none` but in order to set it to None you also need to set it as `Secure` as i read from here `https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/`

Is there an alternative in case I want to work with HTTP and i want the client to send the cookies to the server

Answer (score 0):

Well there are 2 possible solutions for this matter:

1. You can set the cookie as secure + SameSite->None to make the browser automatically send the cookies for every request
2. You can tell the browser to send the cookies yourself on each request via:
   [Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i)
   [Fetch API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558264/fetch-api-with-cookie)