# fetch url with cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

so im **scraping** a web and i need to use a specific cookies but i dont know how to exactly use "fetch"

```
    const url="https://www.example.com";
    let response = await fetch(url),
        html = await response.text();

    let $ = cheerio.load(html)

    var example= $('.exampleclass').text();
```

Now i can **scrape** the web but in case i would have to use a specific cookies i dont know how to put in on the fetch.

In python was something like that

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Which module are you using? [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)?

Comment: You can refer to this [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558264/fetch-api-with-cookie)

Comment: @Muhammad.fatiu That question is about in-browser fetch; OP's question is about node.

Comment: Anyway, to set a cookie you need to add a [Cookie header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie): something like `await fetch(url, { headers: { "Cookie": "a=b" }})` should do it.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ and __scraping__ not scrap and scrapping

Answer (score 0):

You can add the cookies on the headers on `node-fetch`, I've made a helper function that you can use for your purposes:

```
const cookieMaker = object => {
    const cookie = [];
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
        cookie.push(`${key}=${value}`);
    }
    return cookie.join('; ');
};

const fetchText = async (url, cookie) => {
    const r = await fetch(url, {
        headers: {
            Cookie: cookieMaker(cookie),
        },
    });
    return await r.text();
};

fetchText('http://someurl.com', { token: 'abc', myValue: 'def' });
```