# How to set Cookie in react fetch

Tags: reactjs

Here is my curl code which one i am trying over swagger is working.

```
    curl -X 'GET' \
    'http://178.154.200.180:8080/api/v1/user/brands' \
    -H 'accept: application/json' \
    -H 'Cookie: wba-session-id=13afbb83-a4e1-4fd5-b8bb-b35187164188'
```

The same curl code i converted to react fatch but it is saying un authorized.

```
        useEffect(() => {
            let headers = {
                'accept': 'application/json',
                'Cookie': '13afbb83-a4e1-4fd5-b8bb-b35187164188'
            }
            fetch('http://178.154.200.180:8080/api/v1/user/brands', { headers: headers })
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then(res => { 
                alert(res)
             })
        }, [])

http://178.154.200.180:8080/api/v1/user/brands
```

url works over browser

Please take a look where i am doing wrong.

Comment: look into [cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Cors already set. These is no cors error

Comment: maybe share the error message here

Comment: Invalid value for: cookie wba-session-id

Comment: It may refer to cors options. Please share some shots from browser logs

Comment: This is the only log i am getting

Comment: try `'Cookie': 'wba-session-id=13afbb83-a4e1-4fd5-b8bb-b35187164188'` , adding `wba-session-id=` to the fetch cookie line

Comment: Tried strill not working.

Comment: Same working in postman

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558264/fetch-api-with-cookie