# How to post a request with cookies js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, xmlhttprequest, fetch

It's my first time asking something here and my first language is not english, so I am sorry if I get anything wrong. So I have been using selenium's execute_script to detect if a certain html element in a page changes, it then posts a request to a completely different domain. My problem is that the post requires cookies, and I have no idea how to set them. It would be really helpful if anyone knew how to set the cookies with fetch/knew another way to post e request with cookies using javascript.

Comment: Does this help? [Fetch API with Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34558264/989920)

Comment: It helps a lot :D I am just wondering how to set the cookies using javascript, but I will try to figure that out. thank you for the help :)

Comment: Does this also help? [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)