# Fastify + Svelte + NGINX: Can't get cookie to drop in local development

Tags: node.js, nginx, cookies, svelte, fastify

I have a personal project I'm working on in local development. Up front, the issue is that I can't get a JWT authorization cookie to set in my browser. The setup is:

-NPM Workspaces project, with the separate workspaces being the client (Svelte app) and API (Fastify server)
-NGINX as the web server

Link to the repo is here: https://github.com/stevedoesitall/starter-template

In the [server file](https://github.com/stevedoesitall/starter-template/blob/main/apps/api/src/server.ts), I register the Fastify cookie, CORS, and JWT  plugins. Then in my [users/controller file](https://github.com/stevedoesitall/starter-template/blob/main/apps/api/modules/users/users.controller.ts), upon a successful request, I add a user to the DB, generate the auth token, and send back the cookie.

Within my main [App.svelte file](https://github.com/stevedoesitall/starter-template/blob/main/apps/client/src/App.svelte), I make the request to the users/signup endpoint.
Upon submitting, I see the cookie in my Network:

```
set-cookie: authorization=e--cookie value here--; Max-Age=86400000; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict
```

I've tried a bunch of different combinations of cookie parameters, fetch header parameters, tweaking my browser cookie settings, etc. and I can't get anything to work.

Additionally, I have both my domain and subdomain configured locally with the proper SSL certs and running both on NGINX. I have an example of how that's configured in the repo [here](https://github.com/stevedoesitall/starter-template/blob/main/nginx/server.conf).

Any help getting the cookie to set so I can continue my testing would be hugely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558264/fetch-api-with-cookie) help?

Comment: Thanks! That didn't do the trick unfortunately, but I appreciate the help!