# How to store cookies in cookie storage when I make a fetch request

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to access profile API from my backend using fetch requests in react. But I get server errors all the time. it seems the backend does not recognise that I am logged in though login request works fine. I really need help with this. Been stuck for weeks.  Aall the necessary code and errors are in the link below since I asked this question some time ago but couldnt get an answer. Thank you in advance.

[previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72988931/how-to-access-profile-api-from-the-frontend-user-is-logged-in-from-the-backend)

Comment: You can bring your code here as well. Each question is considered as a separate one, so you should give a full context for your question. If you think this is your previous question extent, you can modify your previous question instead.

Comment: could you please use the link to access the question so you can help me answer?