# Need to add cookie to API header in opened web browser running with python selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Now I am working with python selenium and I want to know one problem.
I am running js script in opened web browser

```
result = driver.execute_script('''
        return await fetch("https://example.com", {
            "headers": {
                "accept": "application/json",
                "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
                "traceparent": "00-3e3ff822cf02c630cff68ed054769214-62c0b9ae093c2f05-01",
                "Referrer-Policy": "origin"
            },
            "body": null,
            "method": "GET"
            })
            .then(json => json.json());
        ''')
```

My problem, When I run js script and call api, the result returns "session is expired".

For fix this, Will I add cookie in fetch header?
I thought, fetch will process cookie automatically if js is running in opened web browser.

Am I wrong?

If you know about this, please answer me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch API with Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558264/fetch-api-with-cookie)

Comment: @MattMorgan Thanks for reply. but It's another problem. I want to know fetch problem in opened web browser.

Comment: Is it a different problem though?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#parameters

Comment: @MattMorgan thanks I get idea for your referrence url

Comment: @MattMorgan  we will use include instead of  credentials: "same-origin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `credentials: "include"` so that cookies and other credential-related info, like HTTP authentication entries and TLS client certificates are sent with the request. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#credentials).

Something like this should work:

```js
return await fetch("https://example.com", {
    "headers": {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "traceparent": "00-3e3ff822cf02c630cff68ed054769214-62c0b9ae093c2f05-01",
        "Referrer-Policy": "origin"
    },
    "body": null,
    "method": "GET",
    "credentials": "include" // <---
})
.then(json => json.json());
```

Comment: COOL, thanks.
Include is correct key.

Comment: I have one more question. Did you hear about "fansight-tab" option?

Comment: Please check this image.
https://prnt.sc/RUyiNEdelnGJ

Comment: I never heard of it and I couldn't find it in the `fetch` documentation. Where did it come from?

Comment: mmm, okay thanks. I think it's man-made option