# Python, blur core api 403

Tags: python, cloudflare

I got a problem:

```
curl https://core-api.prod.blur.io/v1/prices -H "User-Agent: randomtext" - Status code: 200

response = httpx.request('GET', 'https://core-api.prod.blur.io/v1/prices', headers={
'Host': 'core-api.prod.blur.io',
'Accept': '*/*',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Connection': 'close',
'User-Agent': 'useragent'
}, verify=False, proxies={"all://": "http://127.0.0.1:8080"}) - 200 (BurpSuite)

response = httpx.request('GET', 'https://core-api.prod.blur.io/v1/prices', headers={
'Host': 'core-api.prod.blur.io',
'Accept': '*/*',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Connection': 'close',
'User-Agent': 'useragent'
}, verify=False) - 403
```

How can I fix this?

Code or any    answer

Comment: In what way is this Python related?

Comment: Tim Roberts, I need a python solution. Curl works, python though burp suite proxies too. But I don't use to use curl in python or run burp suite

Comment: is this link helpful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75776383/automated-request-to-core-api-prod-blur-io

Comment: No, I am trying to make a request without selenium