# FastAPI google authlib doesn't work from html (works from swagger)

Tags: fastapi, fetch-api, authlib

I have Google OAuth working with FastAPI and authlib, following  [this example](https://github.com/authlib/demo-oauth-client/blob/master/fastapi-google-login/app.py) and building off the official [security tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/). This is working via FastAPI's built-in swagger UI, and I can see that I'm only able to access my protected routes if I have logged in with my google user via the `fastapi.security.OAuth2PasswordBearer` form, which is good.

However, I can't replicate this via my "frontend", which is just some html served by fastapi with a button that triggers the typical Google OAuth form. That is, the button contains `<a href="/login">Google</a>`. This ultimately takes me to my `/token` endpoint and prints the `{"access_token": <my_token>, "token_type": "bearer"}`, which seems good.

In reality, once this token is correctly received, I need to redirect to one of my protected routes. In order to redirect, I can't simply use that `<a>`. Instead, I need to bind an `XMLHttpRequest()` to `onclick` that simulate's the `href="/login"` with a `GET` and, if that goes well, then redirects to my protected route. But unfortunately that `XMLHttpRequest()` results in `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8004%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fgoogle&scope=openid+email+profile&state=<state>' (redirected from 'http://127.0.0.1:8004/api/auth/login/google') from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8004' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`. I have tried a variety of different  headers and referrerPolicy, as well as `CORSMiddleware`  but so far I am unable to simulate the `<a>` with my `XMLHttpRequest()` .

To be honest, I'm not sure I'm approaching this the right way. Ultimately I'm just trying to get your example code to work not just via swagger but also via my html.

Answer (score 0):

The token is stored in session, and the session is simply a cookie. Normally, cookies are sent with synchronous http requests to the server that set that cookie. However if I understand correctly, you are making a asynchronous http request with `fetch()`.
You can try to enable sending cookies with your `fetch()` requests by trying the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34592377/1380611).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but adding `credentials: "same-origin"` or `credentials: "include"` is not helping. I suppose my first doubt is whether I should be using `mode: "no-cors"` or `mode: "cors"` because depending on that I get different errors in the console. For example it will, respectively, break at `https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/identifier` with a 403 or at `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth` with `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` (even though I've added it to my `fetch()`).

Comment: @JaimeSalazar the final error you mention is a typical CORS error, so you should mode: "cors". The 403 error can maybe be caused by some wrong setting in your Google Cloud Project.

Comment: Ok but then it's likely that I will need `mode: "cors"`? FWIW right now the frontend is part of FastAPI, coming from the same IP and PORT, but in the future I will likely be building a separate frontend. Does that make a difference?