# Flask-login doesn't call load_user, is_authenticated is always false

Tags: reactjs, flask, flask-restful, flask-login

Description:

I'm working on a Flask-React web application that uses Flask-Login for user authentication. However, I'm facing an issue where the load_user function doesn't seem to be called, and authentication is not persisting between requests.

Scenario:
1- send login request -> {'message': 'Login successful'}
2- send /profile request ->
What should I do?

Here's what I have in my code:

## In models.py:#

```
from app import db, ma, login_manager


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    r = Users.query.get(int(user_id))
    print(r)
    return r
```

## In app.py:#

```
# Import the required libraries
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask import Flask

# models.py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash

# Create various application instances
# Order matters: Initialize SQLAlchemy before Marshmallow
db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
ma = Marshmallow()
cors = CORS()
login_manager = LoginManager()  # Initialize login_manager outside of create_app

def create_app():
    """Application-factory pattern"""
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '312312321312' # I added a random number for stackoverflow
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///database.db"
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

    # Initialize extensions
    # To use the application instances above, instantiate with an application:
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    ma.init_app(app)
    cors.init_app(app)

    # Initialize Flask-Login
    login_manager.init_app(app)  # Initialize login_manager with current_app
    login_manager.login_view = 'login'  # Set the login view (adjust 'login' to your actual login route)
    login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'

    return app
```

## In routes.py:#

```
import json

from flask import jsonify, request
from app import create_app, db
from models import Orders, Orders_items, Products, Users, Suppliers
# Load environment variables from .env file
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
from flask_login import login_user, current_user, logout_user, login_required
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt


# Create an application instance
app = create_app()


@app.route('/login',methods=['POST','GET'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        # If the user is already authenticated, return a JSON response
        return jsonify({"message": "User is already authenticated"})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get JSON data from the request
        data = request.get_json()
        if 'email' in data and 'password' in data:
            email = data['email']
            password_candidate = data['password']

            user = Users.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
            if user:
                passwordd = Users.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
                if sha256_crypt.verify(password_candidate, passwordd.password):
                    login_user(user)
                    # You can return a JSON response indicating success
                    return jsonify({"message": "Login successful"})
                else:
                    # Return a JSON response for invalid password
                    return jsonify({"error": "Invalid Password"}), 401
            else:
                # Return a JSON response for invalid email
                return jsonify({"error": "Invalid Email"}), 401
        else:
            # Return a JSON response for missing email or password
            return jsonify({"error": "Missing email or password"}), 400

    # Handle GET request if needed
    return jsonify({"message": "GET request is not supported for this endpoint"}), 405

@app.route('/logout', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def logout():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        logout_user()
        # Return a JSON response indicating successful logout
        return jsonify({"message": "Logout successful"})
    else:
        # Return a JSON response for unsupported HTTP method
        return jsonify({"error": "Method not allowed"}), 405


@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET'])
@login_required  # Ensure that the user is logged in to access the profile route
def profile():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        user_details = {
            "user_id": current_user.id,
            "username": current_user.username,
            "email": current_user.email
            # Add more user attributes as needed
        }
        return jsonify(user_details)
    else:
        # Handle the case where the user is not authenticated
        return jsonify({"error": "User is not authenticated"}), 401




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## Note:#

The real structure of my application is different, and it uses blueprint but I tried to minimize the problem as much as possible to focus on the problem itself but still couldn't solve it.

I tried putting login_manager in app.py thinking maybe there is a problem in the imports

**Edit**
It works using Postman, any idea why?

Comment: The code looks correct but I'm not a React specialist. I assume that the session cookie is not sent. Are you using a proxy for your calls from React to Flask? Do you use the Fetch API for your communication? If so, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34558264/13708022) might help you. So that the cookies are sent with the request.

Comment: The application does run with React as Frontend, but currently I am testing only Backend side using Postman, I am assuming applying /login then /profile should should me the details of the current authorized user.