# how to use fetch api in javascript to get response from C# Web method?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, fetch, webmethod

**Java script Code** :

```
var AllTeams;

function GetAllTeams_ProductSamplePerClass() {
    return fetch("../Pages/Product.aspx/GetAllTeams", {
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'MyTeam'
    }
    ).then(response => {
        AllTeams = response.json();
        console.log('success getall teams', response);
        console.log('teams', AllTeams);
        return AllTeams;

    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('Error in getall teams', error);   
    })
}
```

***C# Method in aspx file :***

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<MyTeam> GetAllTeams()  
{
    TeamServiceClient TeamSvc = new TeamServiceClient("wsHttpBinding_TeamWsEndPoint");

    try
    {
        return TeamSvc.GetAllTeams();
    }
    catch
    {
        TeamSvc.Abort();
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        TeamSvc.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're having?  Are you getting an error?  Unexpected results?  Please describe the problem.

Comment: in dev tool  get this in console success getall teams 
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3737/Admin/Pages/Product.aspx/GetAllTeams", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body
:
(...)
bodyUsed
:
false
headers
:
Headers {}
ok
:
true
redirected
:
false
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
type
:
"basic"
url
:
"http://localhost:3737/Admin/Pages/Product.aspx/GetAllTeams"
__proto__
:
Response

Comment: "Success" usually isn't an indication of a problem.  Do you have an *actual problem* that you're observing somewhere?  (One thing to note is that your `return` statement in your `then()` callback doesn't actually do anything, you don't need that.)

Comment: when i adding response.json() give me this error in console : teams Promise__proto__: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected"[[PromiseValue]]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4

Comment: Sounds like the response may not be JSON.  In your browser's debugging tools, what is the actual response from the server?

Comment: That is way i ask , i hit break point in .net to see if fetch function call my c# method or not i found no access in c# method , this mean it's not call function and back with empty response that what is guess , so have you any idea about getting by fetch api from c# method ?

Comment: So if it's not reaching your server-side code, what *is* it doing?  Use your browser's debugging tools.  Specifically on the network tab.  Is the HTTP request what you expect it to be?  What is the server's response?  Is the response an error?  What is that error?

Comment: now i checked from network tab, and i found the requerst Request URL: http://localhost:3737/Admin/Pages/Product.aspx/GetAllTeams
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK , but the response tab give me all aspx page that is not what i expect , i need only data from web method name GetAllTeams i used to get that by  xhr = $.ajax but it's not the same for fetch

Answer (score 0):

After search one day and keep trying and test ,  i found the issue that made fetch api not reach to the server is this line was not in  javascript  headers: {
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
this made the response not html response as before  but made the response  object that came from web method 
thanks @David for your help 
the link i searched and found the solve  :
[Fetch API call causes new Asp.net session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51291831/fetch-api-call-causes-new-asp-net-session)