# How to access session data across servlets in java?

Tags: java, reactjs, session, servlets

I am working on an application with react on the front end and java(running on tomcat server JDK17) in the backend. Whenever I login into the application, I send the user data to the server(java) and see if the user exists in the database. Whenever I move across the components in the react application, I would like to check if the user is authenticated/allowed to use that particular component. Hence I stored the data onto a session in the login servlet. I tried to access the session from another servlet called AuthenticationServlet, it returns null. Do I have to configure something so that I can access the data across all the servlets.

This is how I set the session data in the login servlet:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("uname", uname);
```

Printing it on the console in the same servlet displays the username.
This is where I'm accessing it(AuthenticationServlet)

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String k = (String) session.getAttribute("uname");
System.out.println(k);
```

This displays null. What am I doing wrong or did I miss something. Much appreciated!

Comment: Check whether your frontend programs allow cookies. Some network libraries do not contain cookies by default. The implementation of the session depends on the jsessionid stored in the cookie. If cookies are not supported, a new session is created for each request.

Comment: @HUTUTU I can find the jsessionid int response header. I don't find it in the cookies tab

Comment: @HUTUTU Can you tell me how I can add those cookies to the browser cookies?

Comment: If you are using Chrome, you need to check "show filtered request cookies". Check two different network requests to see if JSESSIONID is the same. What network library do you use in react?

Comment: @HUTUTU I'm using fetch API to get the data from java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51291831/fetch-api-call-causes-new-asp-net-session

Comment: @HUTUTU I tried this out and it was raising a pre-flight CORS. Is there something that I have to add on the server side as well?

Comment: Did you set credentials to include? If so, I think it should be set to same-origin.

Comment: @HUTUTU In the client side, I have this header ```credentials: "include"``` In the server side I have ```  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "same-origin");``` Still getting CORS error. Anything else I'm supposed to add

Comment: credentials:"same-origin"